Typescript errors in stock Next.js install
Every time I create-next-app using typescript I get hundreds of "Problems" in my tsx files:


I'm not getting errors on build, these seem to be isolated to vscode.
I have uninstalled vscode, uninstalled all extensions, and tried using JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly plugin.
Steps to recreate:

create-next-app@latest
Use all defaults
Open page.tsx

Expecting no red underlines right out of the box.

Looks like an lsp issue. What extensions are you running and have you reset default vscode settings when reinstalling?

Check your tsconfig.json file. It needs to have "DOM" in libs and "jsx": "react-jsx" or similar

Totally agree with @ZachJensz here, definitely a LSP issue. Have you checked that VSCode has selected the right language in the bottom right? Should either be Javascript JSX or Typescript JSX.

@Phil In this case I think it's warranted as the code is irrelevant and the focus is on what vscode is doing

Thanks Fabio Nettis, once I configured the default handling of .tsx files with TypeScript JSX and restarted VSCode it worked!

It would be helpful to share how did you configure the default handling.
